# No internet access when Hyper-V is enabled

Tags: hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

When i enable Hyper-V system function on my Windows 10 then i have no internet access. How can i fix it? When i tried fix it by windows repair tools, then i got message "Ethernet Doesn't Have A Valid IP Configuration". I need this function to debugging Windows Phone application on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Your virtual switch is not configured to get the current Internet connexion.

As I know, Windows 10 inherits many functions of Windows 8, therfor, here is some ressources that you may find by simply searching stackexchange sites :

[Windows 8 Hyper-V - how to give VM internet access?](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access)

And another one that may help :

http://blog.siliconvalve.com/2012/09/26/fix-windows-8-and-hyper-v-virtual-switch-problems/

Comment: It does not work. I do not have access to the internet on my physical computer, not on the emulator.